# Typing in Visual Studio Ctrl + F search window with input method appends result, how to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, search-box, input-method

I use Ctrl + F, to search some characters in current file using with an input method. the new search term (`new`) just append to the old search term(`old`), instead of replacing it:

[image]

How could I make it so that it replaces the old search term when using an input method?

Comment: you might have some luck looking through the search results of googling `site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues "find" "IME" -terminal` or a similar search query. I don't have time to help right now, but I might look more later too. If you don't find anything, I'd suggest also [raising an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md). If you do so, please add a link here to it for posterity.

Comment: @user I could't find an existing issue, so I created one here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181796